# Android studio path is not recognized

Tags: android, android-studio

**This is my problem:**

[image]

**What I tried:**

- Re-installing.
- Doing what it tells me to do on the picture.
- I added the java jdk to my environment variables.

Nothing of those things worked.

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not your JDK. As the error says, the problem is that it can't find the Android SDK.

The path that you put into that box should be something like `/Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk` (OSX) or `C:\Android\SDK` (Windows), depending on where you have installed the Android SDK.

Comment: I understand, but when I use /Users/<user_name>/Library/Android/sdk it won't work. Also I got no clue about where it's located.

Comment: Do you actually have the Android SDK installed there?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this problem:

> 1. Download the android standlone sdk from [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)
> 2. make a directory consisting of android sdk's in your computer and provide that directory path to that pop up.
> 3. Provide the sdk path (the default path is : /opt for Linux based OS and C:\Android\SDK or something like this for windows...

There can be several other ways. You can get more info @ [Android developer site for details](http://developer.android.com/develop/index.html)